# download models.gazebosim.org

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hello,
i would like to have a local copy of models.gazebosim.org. is there any easier way, or a dump file, so i dont have to use wget/curl recursively?
best regards,
-c.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25045/download-models.gazebosim.org/) by [altineller](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23788/altineller/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2020-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Go to [gazebo_models](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models/) on github.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2